# Index of Table Row in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a TableLayout and some unknown number of TableRows that are generated based on what's in the database.

Every row has an OnClick listener attached, however, once the click happens I can't tell (meaningfully) from what row it came from. Is there a way that I can get the index of the tablerow in relation to the TableLayout or should I try something else?

Some code:

```
private void buildBudgetTable() {
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    TableLayout budgetTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.budgetTable);
    budgetTable.removeAllViews();

    try {
        this.budgetItems = Budget.GetEntries(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not load budget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }

    for(BudgetEntryItem entry : budgetItems){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setPadding(1, 2, 1, 2);

        TextView txtLeft = new TextView(this);
        txtLeft.setText(entry.Memo);
        txtLeft.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        txtLeft.setPadding(3,3,3,3);

        TextView txtRight = new TextView(this);
        txtRight.setText(currencyFormatter.format(entry.Amount));
        txtRight.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        txtRight.setPadding(3,3,3,3);

        if(entry.Amount > 0){
            txtRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0x33, 0xEE, 0x33));
            txtLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0x33, 0xEE, 0x33));
        }else{
            txtRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xEE, 0x33, 0x33));
            txtLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xEE, 0x33, 0x33));
        }

        tr.addView(txtLeft);
        tr.addView(txtRight);
        tr.setOnClickListener(this);

        budgetTable.addView(tr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the TableRow's tag:

```
BudgetEntryItem entry = null;
for(int i = 0; i < budgetItems; i++){
    entry = budgetItems[i]; // or budgetItems.get(i), etc
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

    // Set the index as the tag
    tr.setTag(i); // or entry.setTag(entry.index()), etc

    // ...
}
```

Now to grab the index, just convert it back to an int in your onClick which provides you with the originating View.

**An aside**
Some people frown on using Tag's in this manner on the principle that it couples the data layer with the UI layer. An alternative would be to use a Dictionary or Dictionary, etc to access the item indirectly without tying the UI element to the data object.

Comment: You got the variables mixed up, entry isn't the table row. And I wound up just entering the Entry item as the tag.

Comment: You should read the aside and consider setting the tag to the index. It will lead to less possible stray references to data objects that you might want to get garbage collected later and is, overall, better programming practice entirely.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue, this is the solution:

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Current Row Index
                int rowIndex = tableLayout.indexOfChild(v);
                // Do what you need to do.
            }
        });
```

In my case, I had the Listener on a TextView inside a TableRow...

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // The row the view is in
                TableRow row = (TableRow) v.getParent();
                // It's index
                int index = tableLayout.indexOfChild(row);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is the most reliable solution so far proposed.

Comment: Superb solution. No need of complex calling of objects. Use the onboard methods.

Comment: @Ullauri, It's working like charm and pleasure to upvote it. :)

Comment: Thanks just what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setId(i);

    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tabele row clicked "+ Integer.toString(v.getId()) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
```